# expo-location's getCurrentPositionAsync() is taking too much time to fetch location in iOS devices

Tags: react-native, expo, location

I am using `getCurrentPositionAsync()` from `expo-location` to fetch user’s location and this is how I am using this,

```
import * as Location from "expo-location";

Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
    accuracy: 6
}).then(currentPosition => {
   console.log('user location', currentPosition);
});
```

In all `Android` devices it’s taking hardly 2 seconds to capture location. But in all `iOS` devices it takes more than 8 seconds(I am confirming this by testing in multiple `iOS` devices) even though mobile network is so good.

Do I have to do anything else especially for the sake of `iOS` devices?

If nothing is required especially for `iOS` devices, May I know why is it taking too much time in `iOS` devices only?

Answer (score 4):

Ok I had the same problem as you. I found a better option: using `getLastKnownPositionAsync` instead of `getCurrentPositionAsync` .

Bear in mind that `getLastKnownPositionAsync` is to be used if accuracy is not of paramount importance, it won't be the most updated position but much faster than `getCurrentPositionAsync`

Answer (score 1):

Try set accuracy low as below:

```
const isAndroid = Platform.OS == 'android';
const location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({ accuracy: isAndroid ? Location.Accuracy.Low : Location.Accuracy.Lowest, })
```

*Android does not support Lowest